# How to close Open-Relay

Tags: exchange-2003

We are trying to get MessageLabs service up and running. We have been asked to make sure that we do not allow Open-Relay so that the traffice is minimised for them.

How do I do this? Windows Server 2003 with Exchange 2003.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You go into ESM, go to Administrative Groups ->  -> Protocals -> SMTP. Then right click on  select properties, go to the Access tab, Click the relay button then Make sure it is set to "only the list below" Make sure your computers/subnets that your trust are in the box below. You should be good at that point.

Comment: So in that section is the exchange IP Address, as well as 127.0.0.1. Should I removed the 127 address?

Comment: 127.0.0.1 is localhost. There's no need to remove it.

Comment: Neither ip address needs to be in the list, so remove them both.

Comment: What about all this crap from MS? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/kb00324958.aspx

Comment: Well that article is for SBS in a very specific scenario. I can tell you from years of administering Exchange that by default, the list does not need to be populated in order for Exchange users to send email.

Comment: Does anyone know about port 25? I am very confused as if whether this needs to be open/closed?

Comment: TCP port 25 is for the SMTP service. The SMTP service should be running on your Exchange server and you should have port 25 open on your firewall for the Exchange server for both inbound and outbound traffic.